# Javascript Validation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html has something like this:

```
<html>
<table class="MyTable" id="idMyTable">
<tr>
<td>
<select class="mySelect">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" class="myInput"/>
</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="mySelect">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" class="myInput"/>
</td>
<tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="validate()"/>
</html>
```

Inside the validate method I want to check if the user has selected B option then that corresponding input field must not be blank. How can this be done using jQuery?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Nothing. I am learning jQuery. :)

Comment: Learning and trying must be all in same pace.without trying anything learning is waste a google search had given you lots of ideas

Comment: @soumyajitdas Kindly refer this link for learning http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/index.htm. It has lots of examples.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Thanks guys. A google search was not helping. Will make sure to post my code from next time. Appreciate all the help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add options like this first to evaluate values properly..

```
<select class="mySelect">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

> ```
> And here is the logic goes under validation method
> ```

```
$(".mySelect").each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "B")
  {
    if($.trim($(this).closest("myInput").val()) == '')
   {
       // Validation logic here
   }
  }
});
```

And if you don't want the options with value as provided above then check for the selected text of the option using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$(".mySelect").each(function(){
    if($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0)
    {
        if($(this).closest(".myInput").val() == '')
        {
            alert("this input is not valid");
            return false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It helped with a minor modification. $(".mySelect").each(function(){
    if($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0)
    {
 if($.trim($(this).closest(".myInput").val()).length <= 0)
        {
            alert("this input is not valid");
            return false
        }
    }
});

Comment: mark it as accepted answer if you find so.